# Locking out button using python

Tags: python, django

I have a django app and what i want to do is when a html button is pressed i want to have a pop up window locking out the current page saying "Assignment submitted". I want the user to be able to be able to submit again at the begining of each new day. so hence only being able to click the submit button once a day. I know i will have to use the datetime function to access the current day and lock the site out until tomorrow. Any one know any handy tutorials or things i should look up?

```
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="window.open('submit')">
```

I guess the cleanest way is to incorporate this locking out functionality in my `submit` python function in `main.py` file.

Comment: It sounds like what you really want to do is disable a page based on a stored timestamp, based on user.  So however you are tracking a user, whether it be cookies, login, ip address or whatever, you want to store the current timestamp when the submit button is pressed, and every time the user brings up the page, check the timestamp and either enable or disable the page accordingly.

Comment: Yes that’s exactly what I want to do.

Comment: I'd expect virtually any django tutorial would include information on enabling/disabling/showing/hiding pages or sections of a page.  It would also show how to store credentials and user history in a database or in cookies.  Have at it!

Comment: great,  any recommendations for good ones?

Comment: You have heard of Google, haven't you?  I use it all the time, even more that StackOverflow.  Try googling "django tutorial"  You'll see tutorials, beginner's guides, getting started, etc.

Comment: Any specific tutorials you'd recommend in particular?

Comment: Never used django.  You'll have to do your own research.

Comment: no worries, thanks.